# How to change Layout attribute inside <include/> completely with java?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a calculator application that has multiple themes. I have designed multiple layout files and trying to change the layout trough  tag if user has changed theme in setting.

Here is how number-pad shows when i change layout manually in xml.

[image]
rectangular.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- all rectangular button codes -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
circular.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- all rectangular button codes -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSource"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:hint="Enter a number"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvTarget"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTarget"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:hint="Do some calculations to see the answer"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/include"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvSource" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/basic_numpad_rectangular_flat_multi_color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalGuideline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Setting"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvSource"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is what i have tried to change layout attribute of include tag from rectangular to circular:

```
View circularComplete =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.basic_numpad_circular_complete, null);
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.include);
viewGroup.removeAllViews();
viewGroup.addView(circularComplete);
```

it changes the layout but doesn't keep the constraints or spaces near each buttons.

[image]

**How to change layout attribute of  programatically so it keeps all the constraints and spaces?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

> ```
> View circularComplete =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.basic_numpad_circular_complete, null);
> ```

to this instead:

```
View circularComplete =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.basic_numpad_circular_complete, viewGroup, false);
```

The second argument to the `inflate()` call is the parent view, used to interpret the inflated view's LayoutParams. Since you are passing `null`, the LayoutParams of the inflated view (most importantly, the `layout_width` and `layout_height`) are ignored, and default values are used instead. For width/height, the default is `WRAP_CONTENT`.

By passing `viewGroup` as the parent (and `false` for the third argument), your inflated view's LayoutParams will be respected, and its size will be set correctly.

You could also *not* pass a third argument at all, and avoid having to do the `addView()` call:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.include);
viewGroup.removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.basic_numpad_circular_complete, viewGroup);
```

vs

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.include);
viewGroup.removeAllViews();
View circularComplete =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.basic_numpad_circular_complete, viewGroup, false);
viewGroup.addView(circularComplete);
```

Comment: it worked but adds a small space(margin or padding) below the design while it's not there when i set layout manually in xml. Do you have any idea what's happening?
https://imgur.com/a/JY2iGKe

Comment: I imagine that it has to do with how the inflated view is constrained. In your normal layout I see that your `<include>` tag has e.g. `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`... are you adding those constraints when you modify the view at runtime?

Comment: No. Got it fixed, the problem was my circular themes had 4dp margin in their xml, when changing from circular to rectangular the margin 4dp was still there. and since we are keeping all the constraint with inflator that 4dp was still there even when changing to another layout.